# How do we explicitly "save" in Google Docs word document?

Tags: google, google-drive

Since I'm using Google Docs to save most of my files, I will visit it many times a day, sometimes to keep notes and stuff.

Usually my edits are quick 10-second edits, and whenever I edit a document and want to close it, I have to wait for Google to save the document before closing it.

With a lot of editing, this slowly gets annoying. I was wondering if there is a way around it, like a simple button that I can click and tell the computer something along the lines of "save and close tab when you are done saving".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of explicitly saving, you can press **Ctrl-S**.

Afraid I can't help with "save and close tab when you are done saving".

Comment: In addition to Dave's answer, each browser will have a shortcut key to close the current tab. For Chrome it is CTRL-W. This was you can press CTRL-S and the CTRL-W and your doc will be saved and tab will be closed.

Comment: @Greg that's what I'm talking about. If I do a Ctrl-S and it is saving halfway and I do a Ctrl-W, the "saving" is gone!